# Descendant operation in natural numbers - definition in first order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I wonder if descendant operation is axiomatizable (or definable) in first order logic. Descendant is:
$0, s(0), s(s(0)),...$ you know it - natural numbers and something like that ....
I was using descendant in prolog, but prolog implement recursion, which is forbidden in first order logic.  Since I know (only know) that recursion is forbidden in first order logic that I expect it is not axiomatized. However, I am trying to prove it, the best by game.  Can you help me ?

**Edit**
It did come some idea to my mind, lets look at it please:
Descendant  operation is in fact some function - intuitively $\lambda n.n+1$.    This function may be represented as graph:
$0->s(0)->s(s(0))->.....$  keep in mind that this graph is infinite and it is correct descendant operation.
Lets consider not correct descendant operation:
$0->s(0)->s(s(0))->...->s^{2^n+1}(0)->s^{2^{n+2}}(0)->0$
We know, that now duplicator has winning strategy on $n$ rounds, therefore this class is not definable (it means that it is no express descendant operation with only one formula FO).

However, We still don't know if this descendant operation is axiomatized (infinite set of FO formulas may be used in this case)

Comment: Why do you think that recursion is 'forbidden' in first order logic? The contrary is true: A very general recursion theorem is provable in $\operatorname{ZF}$.

Comment: Can you express descendent operation in first order logic ?

Comment: First-order logic doesn't express *functions*, it expresses *sentences*. What does "express descendant" mean to you? Are you asking whether there is a set $\Sigma$ of first-order sentences characterizing exactly those structures isomorphic to $(\mathbb{N}, S)$? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, but sentence may express property of some function. I think is there exists set express descendant property of function.

Comment: @HaskellFun What is the "descendant property"? You need to state exactly what it is you're trying to express or show inexpressible. I *suspect* you're asking whether $(\mathbb{N}, S)$ can be characterized up to isomorphism by a first-order theory, to which the answer is "no" by the compactness theorem, but I'm not sure if this is in fact what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, I am probably asking about it. Tell me only what is $S$ in your $(\mathbb{N}, S)$

Comment: And why mu approach (with game) is not ok ?